# Does HBase look at all the HFiles in a store when looking for a cell

Tags: java, hbase

I'm just learning about Hbase.

Let's say I'm looking for a given row-id.  The client finds the region-server & region that stores the row-id by looking up zookeeper, root file & corresponding meta file.  So far so good.

A) The region could have many hfiles that contain the cells for a row-id - is that right?
For example, {row-id-1, col-fam-id-1, col-id-1, val1} could be stored in hfile-1 and {row-id-1, col-fam-id-1, col-id-2, val1} could be stored in hfile-2.  *please note that the col-fam is the same*

B) when I ask for a particular row-id, will HBase look-up all the hfiles in the store to compile all the cells for that row-id?

Answer (score 0):

> A) The region could have many hfiles that contain the cells for a row-id - is that right? For example, {row-id-1, col-fam-id-1, col-id-1, val1} could be stored in hfile-1 and {row-id-1, col-fam-id-1, col-id-2, val1} could be stored in hfile-2. please note that the col-fam is the same

Physically, all column family members are stored together on the filesystem. Because tunings and storage specifications are done at the column family level, it is advised that all column family members have the same general access pattern and size characteristics. All cells in a single column family are stored in a single HFile.

> B) when I ask for a particular row-id, will HBase look-up all the hfiles in the store to compile all the cells for that row-id?

If you were looking up columns from different column families in same query (which is not advisable) then Hbase will handle that for you.

The point is that each flush new file is created. Since the writes initially happens to WAL writes are fast and at point of flush a new HFile is created.

The following link explains in detail : [HBase Internals](http://www.slideshare.net/Hadoop_Summit/hbase-storage-internals)

Comment: I don't understand this, because every-time there is a flush hbase writes to a new hfile.  If you've added a new column to a cf or changed a value of one cell.  How can it be expected that all the cells for that column family are stored in the same hfile?  You can update on cell today another one tmrw and in the meantime there could have been a flush.

Comment: The point is that each flush new file is created. Since the writes initially happens to WAL writes are fast and at point of flush a new HFile is created.

Comment: but wouldn't that mean that a single row-id, col-fam could be split between multiple hfiles?

Comment: Yes that is true. Which is why we would need compaction regularly.

Comment: ok great...so when we do a get given a single row-id, column-family, hbase is forced to look into multiple hfiles - is that right?